# How to get the return code in saltstack state

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

Do you know how I can parse the data from stdout and searching within it?

```yaml
check_satellite_registration:
  cmd.run:
    - name: subscription-manager list
```

For example, see the return data below. How can I evaluate the Status in stdout?

```yaml
retcode:
  0
stderr:
stdout:
  Status: Subscribed
```

If the above status is "Subscribed" then continue the execution of the states, otherwise redo the installation:

```yaml
deploy the http.conf file:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/http/conf/http.conf
    - source: salt://apache/http.conf
```

Comment: What return codes are you expecting (changed/failed/...)?  Have you looked at the [requisite](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html) system? This should cover some common scenarios.

Comment: And what do you want to do afterwards? You've not filled in the `--- code ---`.

Comment: Again, what return code? States don't have return codes. They can fail or succeed, with or without making changes.

Comment: Your example return is from the [`cmd.run_all` execution function](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cmdmod.html#salt.modules.cmdmod.run_all). Not from a state, and certainly not from `file.managed`. Please answer the comments directly. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: trying to parse the data from stdout of the above state and apply condition on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options. They all involve not using a state for the check, because it doesn't do anything stateful.

```yaml
deploy the http.conf file:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/http/conf/http.conf
    - source: salt://apache/http.conf
    - onlyif:
      - subscription-manager list | grep 'Status: Subscribed'

do something else:
  cmd.run:
    - unless:
      - subscription-manager list | grep 'Status: Subscribed'
```

```yaml
{% set status = salt["cmd.run"]("subscription-manager list") %}
{% if "Status: Subscribed" in status %}
deploy the http.conf file:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/http/conf/http.conf
    - source: salt://apache/http.conf
{% else %}
do something else:
  cmd.run: []
{% endif %}
```

Though if your "something else" action is supposed to result in the status becoming subscribed, then you should do it like this instead:

```yaml
register satellite:
  cmd.run:
    - name: my-register-command
    - unless:
      - subscription-manager list | grep 'Status: Subscribed'

deploy the http.conf file:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/http/conf/http.conf
    - source: salt://apache/http.conf
    - require:
      - register satellite
```

Comment: OrangeDog Thank you, it was really helpful your answer.